# Multiple OR/AND. Search clause is not valid

Tags: sql

Here is my query:

```
      cs.SqlWhereClause = "([IsDiscontinued] = 0 AND [Visible] = 1 AND [ProductAvailableForSale] = 1) AND ";
        cs.SqlWhereClause += "[LongDescription] like '%ct.%tw.%' ";
        cs.SqlWhereClause += "OR ([LongDescription] like '%\"' ";
        cs.SqlWhereClause += "OR [LongDescription] like '%ct.%' ";
        cs.SqlWhereClause += "OR [LongDescription] like '%14k%' ";
        cs.SqlWhereClause += "OR [LongDescription] like '%18k%' ";
        cs.SqlWhereClause += "OR [LongDescription] like '%10k%' ";
        cs.SqlWhereClause += "OR [LongDescription] like '%12k%' ";
        cs.SqlWhereClause += "OR [LongDescription] like '%cttw%')";
```

Here is what I want to be returned:

items that are: not discontinued, visible, and available for sale

AND

items whose longdescriptions are like '%ct.tw.%' OR are like '%ct.%' etc..

adding the parenthesis after the first OR and after the last OR is giving me the error. i haven't been able to debug it. any ideas?

Comment: What is the error message ??

Answer (score 1):

You should add the first paranthesis before the first or. Like this:

```
cs.SqlWhereClause = "([IsDiscontinued] = 0 AND [Visible] = 1 AND [ProductAvailableForSale] = 1) AND ";
cs.SqlWhereClause += "([LongDescription] like '%ct.%tw.%' ";
cs.SqlWhereClause += "OR [LongDescription] like '%\"' ";
cs.SqlWhereClause += "OR [LongDescription] like '%ct.%' ";
cs.SqlWhereClause += "OR [LongDescription] like '%14k%' ";
cs.SqlWhereClause += "OR [LongDescription] like '%18k%' ";
cs.SqlWhereClause += "OR [LongDescription] like '%10k%' ";
cs.SqlWhereClause += "OR [LongDescription] like '%12k%' ";
cs.SqlWhereClause += "OR [LongDescription] like '%cttw%')";
```